# Unable to parse through confusing JSON data in Python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to parse through the JSON data in Python. I've got the data via a `requests.get()` call and stored it in `resp`, then for reading it I'm trying:

```
 try:
                for item in resp.json():
                        print item
 except:
            e = sys.exc_info()[0]
            print "Bad Request\n"
            print e
```

Which gives me

```
standing
leagueCaption
matchday
_links
```

The information I want is in standing, however when I try `print item['standing']` I get a `<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>` exception thrown and the test fails out. The JSON data can be found [Here](http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/426/leagueTable)

```
{
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http:\/\/api.football-data.org\/v1\/competitions\/426\/leagueTable\/?matchday=26"
    },
    "competition": {
      "href": "http:\/\/api.football-data.org\/v1\/competitions\/426"
    }
  },
  "leagueCaption": "Premier League 2016\/17",
  "matchday": 26,
  "standing": [
    {
      "_links": {
        "team": {
          "href": "http:\/\/api.football-data.org\/v1\/teams\/61"
        }
      },
      "position": 1,
      "teamName": "Chelsea FC",
      "crestURI": "http:\/\/upload.wikimedia.org\/wikipedia\/de\/5\/5c\/Chelsea_crest.svg",
      "playedGames": 25,
      "points": 60,
      "goals": 52,
      "goalsAgainst": 18,
      "goalDifference": 34,
      "wins": 19,
      "draws": 3,
      "losses": 3,
      "home": {
        "goals": 33,
        "goalsAgainst": 7,
        "wins": 11,
        "draws": 0,
        "losses": 1
      },
      "away": {
        "goals": 19,
        "goalsAgainst": 11,
        "wins": 8,
        "draws": 3,
        "losses": 2
      }
    },
```

I've tried `item['standing']['position']` as well, and it fails then as well.

Comment: what is the exact error thrown

Comment: You just have a dictionary. Iterating over a dictionary only gives the *keys*.  Store `response.json()` in a variable and start using the dictionary. There is nothing special about JSON here.

Comment: @depperm: the OP is swallowing all exceptions, but I'd wager it is `TypeError: string indices must be integers`.

Comment: catching all exceptions like that is the best way for your program doing ... nothing.

Comment: I'm pretty new to Python & JSON. I've changed the exception code, so it's now giving `<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>` so I think @MartijnPieters is on the right track. However I'm still not 100% sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `item` you're trying to use is not the json dictionary. Try doing:

```
data = resp.json()
print(data['standing'])
```

Since you're still having issues, this is probably the exact code you're after:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/426/leagueTable')
data = response.json()
print(data['standing'])
```

Note that I don't use a for loop at all, as it's not required.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing in my example isn't it?

Comment: No. When you say `for item in resp.json:` `item` is the *key*. You could use `for key,value in resp.json:` then you could say `value['position']`

Comment: @JeremyS. I've changed my code call to be `for key,value in resp.json():` and then `print value['standing']` which I believe is what you're suggesting, and I'm getting the same `ValueError` exception.

Comment: @rofls Looks like I've got it working now, and then I can just used `for team in date['standing']` to loop through. Thanks! Still a bit confused about the difference, but at least it's working.